# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Web.Services3, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am working on ASP.NET MVC4 (Visual Studio 2012), while adding a Controller I am getting error as :

```
---------------------------
Microsoft Visual Studio
---------------------------
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Web.Services3, Version=3.0.0.0, 
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. 
The system cannot find the file specified.
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

I am not getting what could go wrong. Not sure what details could I provide to get hold of the issue.

Comment: This might help you http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/6060be38-99a4-4c96-a2ae-9f10bf5af093/wse-30-could-not-load-file-or-assembly?forum=asmxandxml

Comment: Oh, good one. Didn't know where it originates, I just know that it can be deployed like any other assembly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need a dll called `Microsoft.Web.Services3.dll` in your output folder. That's a component which is used by a few older libraries. You should find it somewhere on your Computer or using Google.

Answer (score 15):

Cause
This is caused by a reference to Microsoft WSE3.0 components in the web.config file. The same error could occur while building when the dll is referenced elsewhere.

Solution

To fix this, either install the MS WSE3.0 add-on (available for free from Microsoft's site) or edit the web.config file to remove the reference, which is not required for normal operation:

1 - Open the web.config file in the root of your site

2 - Find the following line and comment it out:

```
<add assembly="Microsoft.Web.Services3, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
```

3 - Save and close the web.config file and try again

Comment: +1 and here is a link as well: 
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=14089

Comment: This worked for me. All the regsrvs32, gacutil -i and installing WSE 3.0 didn't worked.